# Android SQLite Cursor out of bounds exception on SELECT count(*) FROM table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

The following function is giving me an out of bounds exception...

```
public void count(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = table.getWritableDatabase();
    String count = "SELECT count(*) FROM table";
    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
    int icount = mcursor.getInt(0);
    System.out.println("NUMBER IN DB: " + icount);
}
```

It's meant to return the number of rows in the database. Anybody know whats wrong? am I perhaps doing this task the wrong way?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You missed out

```
mcursor.moveToFirst();

public void count(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = table.getWritableDatabase();
    String count = "SELECT count(*) FROM table";
    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
    mcursor.moveToFirst();
    int icount = mcursor.getInt(0);
    System.out.println("NUMBER IN DB: " + icount);
}
```

But you should use better methods for this task, like the inbuilt helpers of DatabaseUtils

such as

```
public long count() {
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,'tablename');
}
```

You might find helpful to use `DatabaseUtils.longForQuery()` to get the first column long value, when you have where query for the total count. It's simpler and you do not need that bunch of work with the Cursor.

Comment: Aidan, you should click the "tick" mark if you feel this is the right answer.

Comment: Interesting - I would have expected creating a new Cursor would move it to the first record instead of "before first" - good to know Android adds that concept too (I'm more used to having only an "after last"). Wondering too, what's better, doing this (I would expect so), or `SELECT * FROM table` and then `getCount()` on the resulting cursor?

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ You can mark an answer as accepted only after 15 minutes. @Joubarc probably the DatabaseUtils are way more optimized, that the code you do with getCount();

Comment: `DatabaseUtils` may possibly be well optimised, but if you've already done the query and have the `Cursor` then I very much doubt calling `getCount()` on it will be any slower.

Comment: @Pentium10:  Is "DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries" still a good choice or has it been deprecated?

Comment: Ok.  Are the DatabaseUtils methods going to be quicker for a large number of rows vs. using getCount() method?

Comment: No, you should not think that one method is faster then the other at execution time. But it's easier and faster for the developer to apply and write code using these.

Answer (score 3):

need to move the cursor to the first (and only) row

```
Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
mcursor.moveToFirst();
int icount = mcursor.getInt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this if you want to get Number of Rows for Specific ID or Value

```
public int numbersOfrows (int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numbersOfrows = 0 ;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from table_name where Column_name = 'yourValue'")
        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            numbersOfrows = c.getInt(0);
        }

        return numbersOfrows ;
    }
```