# SQLite Count Rows Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I think I have got a script that will work for this, but im struggling to get the value out into a variable and post it into a textview and eventually compare it to another integer.

```
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

private long fetchPlacesCount() {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DB_TABLE;
    SQLiteStatement statement = mDatabase.compileStatement(sql);
    return (int) statement.simpleQueryForLong();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use the provided DatabaseUtils class for the query.There is something similary here [Android SQLite Cursor out of bounds exception on SELECT count(*) FROM table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094257/android-sqlite-cursor-out-of-bounds-exception-on-select-count-from-table)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about that. I still have the problem though that it is returning a long value not an int.

Comment: Do have a problem with the long that is being returned?

Comment: Sorry im not explaining this very well. I want to compare the count value to an int and also output it. The problem at the moment it outputting it as I am getting "The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (long)"

Comment: This should do setText(String.valueOf(longval)).

Comment: Brilliant that solved that issue. Now how am I able to compare a long and an int. I'm trying to use if (nextvalue.equals(icount)){} But am getting the error "Cannot invoke equals(long) on the primitive type int"

Comment: It seems to me you are new to Java or programming altogether. See if you can get your hands on a good Java book at first. Searching for answers for each line of code may not be best strategy to develop good applications. BTW == is used to compare primitive types.

Comment: Ha yes I am new. I'm getting there, but every now and then something like this stumps me. I thought == only compared references ... or something like that.