# Android: SQLite, How to Select count(*) from multiple tables?

Tags: android, sql

If I use cursor, I can't use "cursor.getString" with the following code. 
And I found that "Cursor.count = 0".

But if I execute this code in the adb shell, I can get the result "10|15|".

May I know the reason or how can i achieve my goal? Many thanks.

```
select (select count(*) from table1) as count1, (select count(*) from table2) as count2;
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing with a cursor ? How are you getting it ? (content resolver, exec raw sql, etc etc).

There are [more correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094257/android-sqlite-cursor-out-of-bounds-exception-on-select-count-from-table?rq=1) ways to do a select count, as the related links clearly show.

Answer (score 0):

So normally use two queries

```
String[] queries = {"select count(*) from table1",
                    "select count(*) from table2"};
```

Then use `Cursor` and perform query and getter for get value.

```
Cursor c = null;
int index = 0;
int totalCount = 0;
while (index < queries.length) {
   c = db.rawQuery(queries[index], null);
   if (c.moveToFirst()) {
      totalCount += c.getInt(0);
   }
   index++;
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to provide the count of the individual rows in the two tables. Wrong answer.